# To what extent are open subsets of a hyperbolic pair of pants determined by the metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $P$ be a pair of pants (a sphere with three open discs removed) and let $g_1,g_2$ be two Riemannian metrics on $P$ of constant Gaussian curvature $K \equiv -1$ such that the three boundary components of $P$ are geodesics. If the identity map $P \to P$  restricts to an isometry $(U,g_1) \to (U,g_2)$ for some open subset $U$, is the identity map necessarily an isometry $(P,g_1) \to (P,g_2)$?

Comment: Of course not: Just take a nontrivial diffeomorphism $f$ of $P$ fixing a proper open subset poiintwise and let $g_1=f^* g_2$.